# CSS - Something like "already clicked" property?

Tags: html, css, properties, hover

So I want when the user clicks on a div, the other div changes color. For that I have:

CSS

```
 .div1, .div2{ background: blue; }
    .div1:active + .div2 { background: red; }
```

HTML

```
<div class="div1">Some text</div>
<div class="div2">Other text</div>
```

With that, when the user clicks on the div1, the div2 changes background but only when the user is still pressing on mouse.

I want to make something like `:visited` property, where the user clicks once in the div1 and the div1 stays with the color changed.

Comment: It seems like a job for javascript...

Comment: @DavidConstantine jQuery, possibly...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [checkbox hack](Http://css-tricks.com/the-checkbox-hack/)

Html:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="toggle">
<label for="toggle"><div class="div1">Some text</div></label>
<div class="div2">Other text</div>
```

Css:

```
input[type=checkbox] {
   position: absolute;
   top: -9999px;
   left: -9999px;
}
.div1, .div2{
  background: blue;
  }
#toggle:checked ~ .div2{
  background: red;
 }
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DSyeD/2/)

Comment: Thanks for focusing on "CSS". Is there anyway to make this uncheckable after check it?

Answer (score 0):

1. for mouse button pressed, you need this: http://api.jquery.com/mousedown/
2. together with some http://api.jquery.com/css/ you can achieve what you need.

If you put your code in a jsfiddle I could help you on it.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<div class="div1"  onclick="style.backgroundColor = '#ff0000';" >some text</div>
<div class="div2">Other text</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use js function for this purpose..

```
function change_color()
{
document.getElementById('change').className  = 'active';
}
```

css

```
.div{ background: blue; }
.active{ background: red; }
```

htnl

```
<div class="div" id="click" onclick="change_color()">Some text</div>
 <div class="div" id="change">Other text</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are not fussed by IE, then you could do the following:

http://jsfiddle.net/seemly/8NgpS/

HTML:

```
<div class="div1">Some text</div>
<div class="div2">Other text</div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
}
.div1 {
    background:#c00;
}
.div2 {
    background:#0c0;
}
.div1:active + div {
    background:#00c;
}
```